# MSP430 Energia Basics ReadAnalogVoltage output 11 Volt

Tags: analog, texas-instruments, launchpad, energia

I'm a beginner starting with the MSP430F5529 Launchpad. I'm just running the Basics code 'ReadAnalogVoltage' that comes in Energia to test the voltage value. I literally have all the wires and potentiometer hooked up the same way as the tutorial says (please refer to the photo), and I didn't change any code at all to the default code that comes in Energia. However, as you can see in my screenshot, my serial monitor is printing out a voltage value of 11 - 12, when I think it should be just about 3, or at most 5. **Could someone please please help me figure out why this might be happening?**[image] [image]

Comment: Try changing the program to use `Serial.println(sensorValue);` and you should be able to get values from 0 to 1023. Then try some test values, e.g. `Serial.println( 100 * (3.0 / 1023.0));` and see if your scaling is working for fixed values.

Answer (score 1):

The MSP430F5529 has a 12-bit ADC, which means that its maximum output value is 4095, not 1023. This explains why your output value is exactly 4 times what you expect. You have to divide by 4095 instead.

Comment: @wannabeengineer, `Serial.println(sensorValue);` as I suggested in the comment below your question would reveal this to you as you adjust the pot to maximum value.